# netbsd - weird hash format for sha1

Tags: hash, sha1, netbsd

On my NetBSD system, there is a password hash in master.passwd that looks like this:

```
$sha1$[5 numbers]$[8 letters]$[17 alpha numeric].[10 alpha numeric]
```

For privacy concerns I left out the actual values. Would someone be willing to explain the different parts of this? I was under the impression that SHA1 resulted in 20 bytes, so I was very confused about what part was the actual hash, and what part was the salt, and what part everything else was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parts can be found in NetBSD `src/lib/libcrypt`.

For the format: [crypt-sha1.c](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcrypt/crypt-sha1.c?rev=1.8&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN)

```
The format of the encrypted password is:
$<tag>$<iterations>$<salt>$<digest>
where:
    <tag>       is "sha1"
    <iterations>    is an unsigned int identifying how many rounds
            have been applied to <digest>.  The number
            should vary slightly for each password to make
            it harder to generate a dictionary of
            pre-computed hashes.  See crypt_sha1_iterations.
    <salt>      up to 64 bytes of random data, 8 bytes is
            currently considered more than enough.
    <digest>    the hashed password.
```

The digest is 160 bits = 20 bytes, but it is encoded using base64 (4 bytes for 3 source bytes) to 28 bytes (with one zero padding byte). See [util.c](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcrypt/util.c?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN) for that.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking in the man page for master.passwd but they seemed to only mention blowfish. Very helpful.

Comment: It's not documented in crypt(3) either. Maybe you should get them to add it to the manpage.